# Как взять названия колонок из значения колонки

Tags: mysql, sql

Как в SQL-запросе подставить в название колонки значения, которые находятся в ней?

[image: img]

В колонке `Тип` содержатся типы сдачи предметов, их надо подставить в названия самой колонки `Тип`. Т.е. чтобы выглядело примерно так:

`|fio|Курс|Семестр|Группа|Оценка|Предмет|eczamen|zachet|`

И под ними должна быть соответствующая оценка.

Comment: И под ними должна быть соответсвующая оценка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фактически руками:

```
select fio,Курс,Семестр,Группа,Предмет,
max(case when Тип='eczamen' then Оценка else '' end) eczamen,|
max(case when Тип='zachet' then Оценка else '' end) zachet
from table
Group by fio,Курс,Семестр,Группа,Предмет
```

Comment: `|` в конце второй строки - это опечатка?

Comment: Все верно! Огромное спасибо!!